# Current amplifier with Mosfet and Op-Amp: Output resistance

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, feedback, nmos

In the following circuit, why is \$R_o\$ given by:

\$R_o=(R_1//R_2)+r_{o2}+g_m .r_{o2}.(R_1//R_2)\$ ?

I dont understand the \$g_m .r_{o2}.(R_1//R_2)\$ parcel

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output resistance is increased beyond the observed value of (ro2+R1||R2) because of the negative feedback effect.

It is known that negative feedback does increase input and output resistance for such a circuit with a factor of (1-loop gain).

For the circuit under discussion the loop gain LG=-(gmRE)=-gm(R1||R2).

Hence , we have (with RE=R1||R2)

r,out= RE+ro2(1+gmRE)=RE+ro2+ro2gmRE.

Feedback model for identificatioin of the loop gan:
This simple model results from (and fulfills) the BJT equations:

Ic=Vbe*gm  ,

Ic~Ie  ,

Vout=-gmRc/(1+gmRE)  .

As can be seen: The loop gain is LG=-gmRe .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0c1Tk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This model is based on the known equations for a BJT.
It can be applied for the FET as well by replacing Vbe by Vgs.

Comment: DDDD - didn`t you have another question regarding current vs. voltage feedback? I have an answer but cannot find the question anymore.

Comment: How do you get that loop gain?

Comment: If you give me some details about that question, i can search for it

Comment: The anser is given in my detailed contribution (EDIT)

Comment: Details: The question was why in Sedra-Smith the feedback scheme in a two-Transistor circuit is using current sampling. This could not derived from visual inspections only.

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary to ad that - if a circuit has a negative feedback loop - this loop is valid for the gain calculation as well as for the input and output impedance calculations.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348273/mos-amplifier-circuits-with-feedback

Comment: DDDD - thank you. How did you find that? I cannot see any "search" function on my screen.